# MongoDB - How do group on date and count elements in array

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

Here is my sample document :

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5eac6572fe57d55a258e645a"),
    "createdAt" : ISODate("2020-05-01T18:07:37.568Z"),
    "user" : ObjectId("5e6dda081c456d3670ba5816"),
    "question" : [
        {
            "round" : 1,
            "attempt" : 1,
            "right" : 0,
            "wrong" : 1,
            "time" : ISODate("2020-05-01T18:07:46.900Z"),
            "_id" : ObjectId("5eac6572fe57d55a258e645b"),
            "questions" : ObjectId("5e81735b286698630dba2be5")
        }
    ],
    "__v" : 0
}
```

I want to group by createdAt and count of total number of question in that date. I tried this but no luck

```js
MyModel.aggregate([
            {  $match: { user: req.user._id } },
            {
                $group: {
                    _id: {
                        createdAt: "$createdAt",
                        //question: "$question",
                        //count: {$count: "$question"} // Giving me an error that $count not found
                    }
                },
            }
        ], function(err, docs) {
            if (err) {
                console.log(err);
            } else {
                res.json(docs);
            }
        });
```

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: So `createdAt` is a date with milliseconds in it, Do you think there will be multiple docs with same `createdAt` ? If Yes then group & merge arrays then do `$size`, otherwise just do `$size` on `question` array..

Comment: Yes in date I don't want milliseconds. Yes with the same createdAt there should be multiple documents.

Comment: So you just want to group on date without hour/second/ms ?

Comment: Yes, I only want year-month-day and it should return the count of question on every date.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try below aggregation query :

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  /** add a new field to each doc with count on `question` array */
  { $addFields: { questionCount: { $size: "$question" } }
  },
  /** group all docs & sum-up question count */
  {
    $group: {
      _id: { createdAt: { $dateToString: { format: "%Y-%m-%d", date: "$createdAt" } } },
      questionCount: { $sum: "$questionCount" }
    }
  }
])
```

**Test :** [mongoplayground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/epK64zxKMDw)

**Note :** You can certainly do this in other way by using `$unwind` as second stage after `$match` on `question` array & then by counting no.of docs in `$group` but `$unwind` might explode your collection if it's huge even after `$match`, So this way it might be better to do.

**Update :** As suggested by @Thee Sritabtim :

```
db.collection.aggregate([
      /** group all docs & sum-up question count using `$size` on array */
      {
        $group: {
          _id: { createdAt: { $dateToString: { format: "%Y-%m-%d", date: "$createdAt" } } },
          questionCount: { $sum: { $size: "$question" } }
        }
      }
    ])
```

Comment: You can also do `{ $sum: { $size: '$question' } }` directly without the `$addFields` step.